Cubic version of Kan loop group
Is there a version of the Kan loop group that is based on cubic rather than simplicial objects?

A cubical model for a fibration (Kadeishvili & Saneblidze 2005) does something like this. I am not making this an answer since I do not know how it evolved and since it is not exactly what you ask for, but still have a look, maybe it will be useful for you

Although still almost ignorant, I decided to make an answer from the very little I managed to learn from the paper I cited in the comment above. At least I will try to convey the main idea and motivation. The reference for the real stuff behind my (most probably) inaccurate answer is
Kadeishvili, Tornike; Saneblidze, Samson, A cubical model for a fibration, J. Pure Appl. Algebra 196, No. 2-3, 203-228 (2005). ZBL1069.55011.
Let me first recall what happens in the "ordinary" simplicial case. One starts with a fibration $F\to E\to B$. In simplicial sets, this is assumed to be a Kan fibration, in topological spaces one may find a simiplicial model by taking singular simplices say.
For each Kan fibration as above one can find a simplicial group $G$, an effective action of $G$ on $F$, a principal $G$-bundle $P\to B$, and an equivalence of the given fibration with $P\times_GF$. The bundle $P$ is pullback of the universal one $WG\to\bar WG$ along a map $B\to\bar WG$ to the classifying space $\bar WG$ of $G$. Data for such a map can be concisely described by what is usually called a twisting function $\tau$ - collection of maps $\tau_n:B_n\to G_{n-1}$ with certain properties. Pullback along the corresponding simplicial map $B\to\bar WG$ then produces an equivalence between $E$ and the twisted cartesian product $F\times_\tau B$ - simplicial set with $n$-simplices $F_n\times B_n$ and face operators twisted by $\tau$ in a certain way. Note that one may always take the loop group of $B$ for $G$ and the universal twisting function corresponding to the canonical homotopy equivalence $B\to\bar WG$, but frequently the structure group may be reduced - for example, if the fibration is trivial, one can choose trivial $G$.
One inconvenience that motivates search for something more clever is that the resulting cochain equivalence of the cochain complex $(C^*(E),d)$ with $(C^*(F)\otimes C^*(B),d_\tau)$, with the "usual" differential twisted by $\tau$, produces an algebra structure on the latter which is not strictly associative. Punchline: analyzing the reasons, the authors come up with the improved notion of what they call truncating twisting function $\tau:B_\triangle\to G_\Box$ from a simplicial set to a monoidal cubical set, which produces a cubical set $F_\Box\times_\tau B_\triangle$ such that the resulting multiplication on the corresponding cochain complex becomes indeed strictly associative.
Let me add that this is not the end of the story. In another paper
Kadeishvili, Tornike; Saneblidze, Samson, The twisted Cartesian model for the double path fibration, Georgian Math. J. 22, No. 4, 489-508 (2015). ZBL1332.55008
the authors show that when further deloopings are possible, i. e. in the situation corresponding in the "usual" simplicial setup to the case when $\bar WG$ is itself an H-space, the similar "strictification" procedure requires once again switching from cubical sets to now permutahedral sets.
